# How to add default value in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I had a table modified to add status column to it in this fashion

```
ALTER TABLE ITEM ADD COLUMN STATUS VARCHAR DEFAULT 'N';
```

However SQLite doesnt seem to add N to the column for any new ITEM created. Is the syntax wrong or is there any issue with SQLite and its support for defaults.

I am using SQLite 3.6.22

Comment: What version of sqlite are you using? I am using 3.6.16 and the sql you provided worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with a frontend you are using to manipulate the db. Have you tried the non-functional `insert` to execute "by hand" (in sqlite cli client)?

Comment: It seems it was actually working , the problem was with frontend using to manipulate the DB

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Looks good to me.  [Here are the Docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

```
sqlite> create table t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, created DATE);
sqlite> .table
t1
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, created DATE);
COMMIT;

sqlite> alter table t1 add column status varchar default 'N';
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, created DATE, status varchar default 'N');
COMMIT;

sqlite> insert into t1 (name) values ("test");
sqlite> select * from t1;
1|test||N
```

**Dump your schema and verify** that your table structure is there after calling ALTER TABLE but before the INSERT.  If it's in a transaction, **make sure to COMMIT the transaction** before the insert.

```
$ sqlite3 test.db ".dump"
```