# regarding arrays in SQLite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an android app and I have to store some data using SQLite db . I have 8 accounts having following elements

- Name  (String)
- Control Type (int)
- Site (String)
- Username (string)
- Password (String)

Now I would like to store, access and modify them using SQLite. I have defined them in a class as follows

```
public class accountsDB {

//private variables
int _id;
int _control_type
boolean _empty;
String _site_name;
String _site_phone_number;
String _user_name;
String _pass;


// Empty constructor
public accountsDB(){

}
```

I am using `_empty` boolean value to check if the account has been added or is empty and I can add new account here if required

I am confused for two things:

1. I need to have 8 copies of this class so I can save,read and edit `account [1-8]`
2. How can I fill default values for `_id` and `_empty` when this db will first be created.

I am new to android and havent used the SQLite DB method to save data. Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your goal is to allow max 8 entries into the accounts table, you can check the record count before inserting new record/account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For id, set it as primary key and auto increment, so you won't need to keep a track of the id.
2. For boolean value _empty, store a default value as 0. See this post for storing boolean values. 
   [Store boolean value in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

1. Please explain in detail.
2. _id is autoincement (no need use default value), for empty you may use SQL parameter - **DEFAULT** ([How to add default value in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254504/how-to-add-default-value-in-sqlite), [Set default value of an integer column SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617610/set-default-value-of-an-integer-column-sqlite))